# Store url in session and go back to the page after fb or google redirection

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, redirect, google-signin

I am trying to store url in session in login.php  and after google or fb redirection to redirect.php I wan to go back to previous page.

**in login.php**

```
<?php
  function getCurrentPageUrl()
    {
      $pageURL = 'http';

      if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on")
      {
        $pageURL .= "s";
      }

      $pageURL .= "://";

      if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80")
      {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
      }
      else
      {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
      }
      $_SESSION['CURRENT_PAGE_URL'] = $pageURL;

    }
?>
```

**in redirect.php**

```
<?php
  if ($_SESSION['CURRENT_PAGE_URL'])
  {
    header('location: '.$_SESSION['CURRENT_PAGE_URL']);
  }
  else
  {

  }
?>
```

Why its not working?

Comment: Could you properly indent the code? Unless i'm mistaken, you declare the `getCurrentPageUrl` function, but you do not call it anywhere, so it's not executed at all. Or maybe there is some additional code somewhere that does call it?

Comment: Yes you where correct. Now its working. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your welcome :).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you did not initialize session on the redirect page. it lacks

```
session_start();
```

so try this

```
<?php
// initialize session if you have not done so

session_start();
function getCurrentPageUrl()
{
$pageURL = 'http';

if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on")
{
$pageURL .= "s";
}

$pageURL .= "://";

if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80")
{
$pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
else
{
$pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}
$_SESSION['CURRENT_PAGE_URL'] = $pageURL;

}
?>
```

**redirect.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['CURRENT_PAGE_URL'])
{
header('location: '.$_SESSION['CURRENT_PAGE_URL']);
}
else
{


}
?>
```